# XGBClassifier's predictions are not probabilities with objective='binary:logistic'

Tags: classification, scikit-learn, xgboost, probability, metric

I am using a XGBoost's **XGBClassifier**, a binary 0-1 target, and I am trying to define a custom metric function. It supposedly receives an array of predictions and a DMatrix with the training set according to the [XGBoost Tutorials](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/custom_metric_obj.html).

I have used `objective='binary:logistic'` in order to get probabilities but the prediction values passed to the custom metric function are not between 0 and 1. They can be like between -3 and 5 and the range of values seems to grow with the iterations.

What is wrong with the code below?

```
import numpy as np
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import brier_score_loss

def brier_score(y_pred, dtrain):
    y_train = dtrain.get_label()
    y_prob = y_pred
    print(f'Min: {min(y_prob)}, max: {max(y_prob)}') # for testing
    return 'Brier_score', brier_score_loss(y_train, y_prob)

SEED = 42
model = XGBClassifier(n_estimators=100, objective='binary:logistic',
                      disable_default_eval_metric=1, scale_pos_weight=12,
                      n_jobs=-1, random_state=np.random.RandomState(SEED), verbosity=1)
model.fit(X_train, y_train, eval_metric=brier_score, eval_set=[(X_test, y_test)], verbose=1)
```

Output:

> Min: -1.21437, max: 1.46595
> ValueError: y_prob contains values less than 0.

Comment: those are probably log-odds?  https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/custom_metric_obj.html#reverse-link-function

Comment: @BenReiniger As that page says, I am using a builtin objective. So shouldn't the raw predictions already be transformed into probabilities?